# PHP class private variable set from different (included) file

Tags: php, codeigniter, class, include, private

I have a class that uses `private` variables those variables are "configuration variables", and I need them to "change" sometimes (in my example if I add new language I need to have in config also new language it's i18n library for CodeIgniter.

I need to set `$languages` and `$special` from database.

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {
  // languages
  private $languages = array(
    'en' => 'english',
    'sk' => 'slovak',
    'fr' => 'french',
    'nl' => 'dutch'
  );

  // special URIs (not localized)
  private $special = array (
    "admin",
    "link"
  );
.
.
.
  function MY_Lang()
  {
    parent::__construct();
.
.
.
```

My thought is that I generate a file and include it in the library.

As follows:
I've tried this, so script will generate file `language_config.php` each time whenever administrator says to.

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    include_once(APPPATH.'/config/system_generated/language_config.php');

    // languages
    $languages = $generated['languages'];

    // special URIs (not localized)
    $special = $generated['special'];
  }
```

and generated file

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
  // languages
  $generated['languages'] = array(
    'en' => 'english',
    'sk' => 'slovak',
    'fr' => 'french',
    'nl' => 'dutch'
  );

  // special URIs (not localized)
   $generated['special'] = array (
    "admin",
    "link"
  );
```

I am not asking how to generate file but how to include and use included file inside library file (**and set variables as private**). <strike>I can not set private variables inside constructor</strike> is there any way to set included variables as private?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I forgot about `private` rules and the whole OOP `$this->...`, code below works fine.

```
class MY_Lang extends CI_Lang {

private $languages;
private $special;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    include_once(APPPATH.'/config/system_generated/language_config.php');

    // languages
    $this->languages = $generated['languages'];

    // special URIs (not localized)
    $this->special = $generated['special'];
  }
```

**EDIT2: another problem with this**

As I added new `__constructor()` to my class, it causes problem because it does not call `__constructor()` from CI_Lang for some reason even in my "added" `__constructor()` there is `parent::__constructor();` which should call `CI_Lang` `__construcotr()`, but it does not. I don't even know how to debug this.

**SOLUTION to EDIT2**

I had 2 constructors in my code. Just merge them.

Comment: extend from class where they were marked as protected. I don't know actually what you want to do.

Comment: I've read this 3 times now, and still don't see why you can't set them in the construct method using `$this->languages = $generated['languages']` ... is there anything more you can add that will make me understand?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE) in path...\application\core\MY_Lang.php on line 23`

Comment: You made it work! I mean after your first comment (before edit) I figured it myself exactly like you did :) thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set them in the construct method `__construct()`, like this:

```
private $languages;
private $special;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->languages = $generated['languages'];
    $this->special = $generated['special'];
}
```

Comment: hello there, this is causing me problems :), can you review edits to my question and see what's happening?